# Reading variables of other Python functions more efficiently

Tags: python, function, flask

I'm trying to refactor some Python code in Flask for a website I build. I think this is a more Python functions problem rather than Flask, so I don't think you need to know Flask to be able to help.

The set-up of each page is done through functions, like:

```
@login_required
def home():
    var1 = ...
    var2 = ...
    var3 = ...
    var4 = ...

    return render_template('page.html',
                            **locals() # returns all local variables
                           )
```

As you can imagine, for a website there's a lot of variables that are shared across pages. So I kept optimizing, to avoid the code that is being repeated, through use of templates and also the use of the following:

1 - Defining functions that assign variables the same. This helps because for each page you'll have many functions (you'll have the regular GET+POST page, as well as other POST pages, such as one per form that you have on that page).

```
def area1_init():
    """
    initializes all variable assignments required for a specific page 
    """
    var1 = ...
    var2 = ...
    var3 = ...
    var4 = ...
    ...

    return (var1, var2, var3, var4...)
```

2 - Use this area1_init() to initialize all variables. I'm still repeating a lot of code (there are a lot of variables), but it's better than defining each variable inside each function.

```
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def home():
    (var1, var2, var3, var4...) = area1_init()

    return render_template('page.html',
                            **locals() # returns all local variables
                           )
```

**Question: How can I avoid needing to manually update the following?**

- In function of step 1, avoid updating "return (var1, var2, var3,
  var4...)"
- In functions of step 2, avoid the first part of variable assignment "(var1, var2, var3, var4...) ="

Updating these manually is getting very time-consuming. I'm sure there's a better way.

Apologies if this has already been answered. I've been using Stack Overflow for years and always found what I needed, but I didn't know how to even search for or title this particular problem.

Comment: Why not returning a `dict` from `area1_init` ?

Comment: I'm convinced that if there's a need to use `locals()`, most of the times there's a design mistake somewhere. Other than that it's difficult to help you with so little information, but my first instinct would be to return a dictionary in `area1_init`

Comment: @ChatterOne My understanding is that using locals how you pass dynamic variables from the Python functions to the HTML template using Flask. If that's correct, then the issue is probably using a sub-optimal framework (Flask), but I might be wrong.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Thank you both for the dictionary suggestion. I'm going to test it and come back to you.

Comment: "using locals how you pass dynamic variables from the Python functions to the HTML template using Flask" absolutely not!! The variables you use in a template are not tied to the locals in any way, except if you do it manually like above. The intended use is like so: `render_template("page.html", foo=somevariable, bar=bar, pagetitle=generate_title(), footer="Go home", ...)`. If you need to pass a lot of the same variables, do `render_template("...", defs=my_defs_object)` and then use `defs.foo`, `defs.bar` etc. in the template.

Comment: How about using a class to manage the data? This is typically what you would do for more complex applications

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a usecase for a dataclass.

From Python 3.6 and up:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, as_dict
from typing import Any

@dataclass
class VariablesForPage:
    var1: int
    var2: str
    var3: bool
    # if you don't want to mess with type annotations,
    # just use typing.Any for everything
    var4: Any

def area1_init():
    return VariablesForPage(
        var1=1,
        var2="hello",
        var3=False,
        var4=[]
    )

@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def home():
    vars = area1_init()
    vars.var1 += 6
    vars.var4.append("bye")

    return render_template('page.html', **as_dict(vars))
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I'm going to try to implement this.

Comment: How would I handle variables that are changing attributes of other classes? I've tried many ways but it doesn't seem to be working. For example, FlaskForms uses ```form.field1``` to show the fields in HTML and ```form.field1.choices``` to update the select field options. ```mr_form = form_classes.RecordsForm()
mr_form.field1.choices = db_func.read_labels()```  I've made the necessary imports. If I define mr_form in the page function, I get an error because the class doesn't take arguments. If defined in the class, I can't change .choices or fields don't show.

Comment: Per the documentation, `FlaskForm` takes arguments normally. This seems like a problem that is separate from the gist of this question.